# When does the defered execution occur?

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2010

I've got a situation which I want to fetch data from a database, and assign it to the tooltips of each row in a ListView control in WPF.  (I'm using C# 4.0.)  Since I've not done this sort of thing before, I've started a smaller, simpler app to get the ideas down before I attempt to use them in my main WPF app.

One of my concerns is the amount of data that could potentially come down.  For that reason I thought I would use LINQ to SQL, which uses deferred execution.  I thought that would help and not pull down the data until the user passes their mouse over the relevant row.  To do this, I'm going to use a separate function to assign the values to the tooltip, from the database, passed upon the parameters I need to pass to the relevant stored procedures.  I'm doing 2 queries using LINQ to SQL, using 2 different stored procedures, and assigning the results to 2 different DataGrids.

Even though I know that LINQ to SQL does use deferred execution, I'm beginning to wonder if some of the code I'm writing may defeat my whole intent of using LINQ to SQL.  For example, in testing in my simpler app, I am choosing several different values to see how it works.  One selection of values brought no data back, as there was no data for the given parameters.  I thought this could potentially cause the user confusion, so I thought I would check the Count property of the list that I assign from running the DBML associated method (related to the stored procedure).  Thinking about it, I would think it would be necessary for LINQ to run the query, in order to give me a result for the Count property.  Am I not correct?

If I eliminate the call to the list's Count property, I'm still wondering if I might have a problem; if LINQ may still be invoked, because I'm associating the tooltip to the control via a function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Any()`, not `Count()`, but even `Any()` will cause the query to be executed - after all, it can't determine whether or not there are any rows in the result set without executing the query.  But there's executing the query, and there's fetching the result set.  `Any()` will fetch one row, `Count()` will fetch them all.

That said, I think that having a non-instantaneous operation that occurs on mouseover is just a bad idea.  There was a build of Outlook, once, that displayed a helpful tooltip when you moused over the Print button.  Less helpfully, it got the data for that tooltip by calling the system function that finds out what printers are available.  So you'd be reaching for a menu, and the button would grab the mouse pointer and the UI would freeze for two seconds while it went out and figured out how to display a tooltip that you weren't even asking for.  I still hate this program today.  Don't be this guy.

A better approach would be to get your tooltip data asynchronously after populating the visible data on the screen.  It's easy enough to create a `BackgroundWorker` that fetches the data into a `DataTable`, and then make the `DataTable` available to the view models in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.  (Do it there so that you don't do any updates to UI-bound data on the UI thread.)  You can implement a `ToolTip` property in your view model that returns a default value (probably null, but maybe something like "Fetching data...") if the `DataTable` containing tool tip data is null, and that calculates the value if it's not.  That should work admirably.  You can even implement property-change notification so that the ToolTip will still get updated if the user keeps the mouse pointer over it while you're fetching the data.

Comment: Oh, I remember that version of Outlook doing that too, when passing my mouse over the printer icon in the menu bar. I hated that!

I like your idea of using a background worker process to fetch the data on a separate thread.  I think I'm going to look into doing that.

Comment: It's funny, because that's seemingly trivial UI problem, and yet it's so annoying that it completely tainted the experience of using the program for me.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, when you call the Count property it iterates over the result set.  Not clear on your last question, but the LINQ probably gets called at the point where you populate your DataGrids, way after the tooltip comes into play.

EDIT: however, this does not mean there is anything wrong with deffered execution or your use of it, it executes at the latest possible stage, right when you need the data.  If you still want to check the Count ahead of actually fetching all the data, you could have a simple LINQ to SQL function that checks for Any() rows.  (Actually Any() is probably what you want more than Count > 0)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Any() in LINQ.  I'll have to look into it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Alex is correct that calling Count() or Any() will enumerate the LINQ expression causing the query to execute. I would recommend re-thinking your design as you probably don't want a query to the database executed every time the user moves his/her mouse. There is also the issue of the delay to query the database. What might be instantaneous on your dev box with a local database might have a multi-second delay on a heavily loaded server. I would recommend creating a DisplayTooltip() function that takes a lazily evaluated LINQ expression. You can then cache the results or apply other heuristics to decide whether you should actually be querying the database or not.